# Alpine Ridge Thunderbolt port bandwidth allocation

Tags: thunderbolt

As we know dual port Thunderbolt controllers are connected via only four lanes, see for example the block diagram below. Now my question is, if you were to plug in two eGPUs (PCI Express enclosures), one in both ports what would happen? How does the system determine bandwidth allocation?  [image: Alpine Ridge block diagram]

Comment: Have you looked up the technical documentation for the standard? If the information is public, it will be in the technical documentation. If the standard is closed, then you may not be able to access that information.

Comment: It is a closed standard.